# IPython magic extension not found

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

I want to look at a database schema using %load_ext schemadisplay_magic then %schema but schemadisplay_magic will load.  I get an error message saying:

No module named 'schemadisplay_magic'

IPython version 5.8.0

I have tried looking it up, but can't find anything about it anywhere.

```
%load_ext sql
%load_ext schemadisplay_magic
```

I expected to be able to load %schema, but i just get an error message.

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'schemadisplay_magic'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though this magic is the creation of innovationOUtside and hasn't been published on PyPi -- here's the [git repository](https://github.com/innovationOUtside/ipython_magic_sqlalchemy_schemadisplay/tree/master/)

you can install it using

```sh
pip install git+https://github.com/innovationOUtside/ipython_magic_sqlalchemy_schemadisplay.git#egg=ipython_magic_sqlalchemy_schemadisplay
```

I was testing it in a virtualenv with a bunch of stuff already installed, so this may not be an issue in a clean environment, but I found that I also needed to upgrade `sqlalchemy-schemadisplay` beyond the 1.3 that's on PyPi. I used this command:

```sh
pip install -U git+https://github.com/fschulze/sqlalchemy_schemadisplay.git#egg=sqlalchemy-schemadisplay
```

Trying to use the ipython magic with `sqlalchemy-schemadisplay 1.3` results in this error:

```
TypeError: create_schema_graph() got an unexpected keyword argument 'restrict_tables'
```